# Run thread every X minutes and update form component c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, class

this is my problem... I have a Windows Forms with a ListBox and a RichTextBox, and a separate class file with some functions...

I know how to update a simple textbox, but not a listview, because if I use the same code, I get 1 new item for every step of myFunc, and the point is this:

```
//myFunc loads
var lv = listProcess.Items.Add("This is my item");
//myFunc step1
lv.SubItems.Add("Column2 step1 status");
lv.SubItems.Add("Column3 step1 status");
lv.SubItems.Add("Column4 step1 status");
//myFunc step2
lv.SubItems.Add("Column2 step2 status");
lv.SubItems.Add("Column3 step2 status");
lv.SubItems.Add("Column4 step2 status");
//myFunc ends
//Remove item "lv" from listview.
```

I hope someone can help me...

> form1.cs

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var func = new System.Threading.Timer(otherclass.myFunc, null, 0, 60000);
    }
```

> otherclass.cs

```
public class otherclass
{
    public static void myFunc(object sender)
    {
        var lv = listProcess.Items.Add("This is my item");
        for(int i; i <= x; i++)
        // Update lv subitems here
        next
        // Update richTextBox1 here when all steps are done

    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me because I'm so lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class otherclass   // otherclass means: should not know about ListViews or RTBs
{
    public static void myFunc(object sender)
    {
        var lv = listProcess.Items.Add("This is my item");
        for(int i; i <= x; i++)
        // Update lv subitems here
        next
        // Update richTextBox1 here when all steps are done

    }
}
```

To your general problem:

1. Use a WinForms timer (not Threading.Timer)
2. When it ticks, start a Backgroundworker
3. The Bgw executes the function in DOWork, update the ListView in Completed.

So what you need is a dataformat (`List<string>` or something more involved) to be returned from `MyFunc()`.

Comment: I've tried with backgroundworkers too, but I want to have otherclass in otherclass.cs, and as far I know, if I call otherclass.myFunc from DOWork... How can I report the status?I mean, DOWork calls a function, but doesn't know about its status? sorry for being that newbie..

Comment: Change `void MyFunc()` to `SomeUsefulType MyFunc()`